# Adding 1 to ColB while looking at values of ColA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to looping through a range to add `1` in `ColB` while looking at `ColA` values and  I want to add 1 from high to low values where 0 will be empty.

Your help will be appreciated.

My try.

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Sheet1.Range("A2" & lastRow).Value > 0 Then
        Range("B2" & lastRow).Value = 1
        ElseIf Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = 0 Then
        Range("B2" & lastRow).Value = ""
    End If
```

2nd try

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A2:A50")
    If c.Value > 0 Then
      Sheet1.Range("B2" & lastRow).Value = 1
    End If
Next c
```

like this

[image]

Comment: Does the screenshot show the desired result?

Comment: Yes. and I want this to add 1 from high to low @VBasic2008

Comment: I don't understand what high to low means? Could you use a practical example?

Comment: I mean to say that first 1 will be added to the highest value then to 2nd highest then 3rd highest and so on and last 1 will be added to the value which is lowest one @VBasic2008

Comment: For the final result, the order doesn't matter. So I still don't get it. I'll post something. Try it, and explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Write to Column If the Value in Another Column is Not Equal to 0

- Note that both solutions do the same.
- For the array version, it is assumed that the range has at least two cells (`A2:A3`). If `A2:A2`, it will fail.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SlowRange()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rg.Cells
        If c.Value <> 0 Then
            c.Offset(, 1).Value = 1
        'Else
        '    c.Offset(, 1).Value = Empty
        End If
    Next c

End Sub

Sub FastArray()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Data(r, 1) <> 0 Then
            Data(r, 1) = 1
        Else
            Data(r, 1) = Empty
        End If
    Next r

    rg.Offset(, 1).Value = Data

End Sub
```